# Ist das noch zu retten?

Tags: sentence-structure

I wonder what kind of structure this sentence has:

Ist das noch zu retten?

It consists of a present tense verb (*ist*) + *zu* + an infinitive (*retten*)

What does it mean when an infinitive with zu is used with a present tense conjugation of sein?

This sentence is probably translated as:

Is that yet to be rescued (saved)?

Or maybe:

Can it still be saved?

I would prefer to write this sentence this way:

*Kann das noch gerettet werden?*

Doesn't it look better that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the infinitive replacement of the *Gerundivum.*

Don't mistake the *Gerundivum* for the *Gerundium — gerund*. German doesn't have the latter. English doesn't have the former.

The Gerundivum is the third participle German has. As the other participles, it can be used like an adjective. *It tells what has to be done* or *what cannot be done*. Compare

> der gerettete Plan — the plan that we have saved
>
> der nicht gerettete Plan — the plan that we have not saved

That's the Partizip II as an adjective.

> der rettende Plan — the plan that saves/saved (us)
>
> der nicht rettende Plan — the plan that does/did not save (us)

That's the Partizip I as an adjective.

> der zu rettende Plan — the plan that has to be saved (by us)
>
> der nicht zu rettende Plan — the plan that cannot be saved (by us)

That's the Gerundivum as an adjective.

So that's the general idea of the Gerundivum. But adjectives also have a predicative use. That's with copula phrases:

> der schwierige Plan — the difficult plan

That's the attributive use.

> Der Plan ist schwierig. — The plan is difficult.

That's the predicative use. Let's use the participles predicatively:

> Der Plan ist gerettet. — The plan is saved.

This works just the same in German and in English. That Partizip II is used as an adjective. This isn't Perfekt but *Zustandspassiv*. The plan is both difficult and saved.

> Der Plan ist rettend. — The plan is saving. (as in life-saving)

This also works just the same in German and in English. This isn't present progressive tense but it tells another property of the plan. Just as before. Now the plan is told to be difficult, saved, and (life-)saving.

And finally, let's try that with the Gerundivum.

> <strike>Der Plan ist zu rettend.</strike>

*Alarm siren goes off.*

Nope. It doesn't work that way. In German, we say

> Der Plan ist zu retten. — The plan has the property of being salvageable, or it has the property of being required to save.

Without the -d that tells apart the infinitive from the Partizip I in German.

In my view, *this is purely because it sounds better.*

But that became a grammar rule.

> Ist das noch zu retten?
>
> Das ist noch zu retten.
>
> Zu retten ist das noch?
>
> Noch ist das zu retten.

Those are perfectly fine and both formal and "street". Native speakers talk that way all the time. Most common:

> Bist du noch zu retten?

In stark contrast,

> Kann das noch gerettet werden?

is grammatical and fine as well but it doesn't get you street credibility. You are clearly an *Ausländer.*

Oh, and as an addition, there are more copula verbs in German, so variants as

> Dieser Plan bleibt zu retten. — This plan still has to be saved.
>
> Gilt dieser Plan als zu retten? — Is this plan considered to be possible to save?

are also fine and common.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation dear Janka. I already knew 80% of what you said above but I have never heard ist + zu infinitive construction before and didn't encounter it in Grammar books either.

Comment: Dieser Plan bleibt zu retten. Is it correct to translate this sentence this way? This plan remains to be saved.

Comment: Yes, you can also translate it that way. As you can see, English doesn't feature the Gerundivum itself, but it has that infinitive replacement to be + past participle which works just the same in some phrasings.

Comment: As I notice now, there is a difference between English and German in this particular kind of structure. In English, past participle is used (to be done) but in German only the verb infinitive is used (zu machen).

Comment: Yes. And in English you can't use it attributively. There is no *to be done thing* but there is a *zu machende Sache*.

Comment: Kann das noch gerettet werden? This is my alternative suggestion which was rejected by you in street talking! Can I still use it in written form of German? It doesn't really matter if I sound like an Ausländer :)

Comment: It's less awkward in writing but still uncommon. That Gerundivum and its infinitive replacement are very common in German. In formal writing they are even more common than in speech.

Comment: Oh! I found something interesting! Instead of saying Ist das möglich? I can say: Ist das zu machen? or Ist das zu tun? They almost mean the same!

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian: Yes, "Ist das zu machen?" means indeed "Is that possible?", but "Ist das zu tun?" Is more like "Does that have to be done?"

Comment: @bakunin - So, I guessed it correctly! But I think ist das zu tun? is more precisely translated as " Is that supposed (expected) to be done? "

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian: Exactly. But always remember the Gerundivum and its infinitive replacement always have two different meanings that can be told apart only from context.

Comment: @Janka: I learned in school "Ist dieser Plan ein zu rettender" as translation for the (latin) Gerundium.

Comment: Gerundivum. In Latin there are both Gerundium and Gerundivum.

Answer (score 1):

The use of infinitive + zu has several cases which demands it.<sup>([1](https://deutsch-mit-anna.de/lektion/infinitiv-mit-zu-und-ohne-zu/))</sup> In general you have constructions with two verbs, in your example ***ist*** and ***retten***. The second verb relates to the first verb, here ***retten*** relates to conservation of state you express with ***ist***.